# Validation of Bayesian hierarchical model

Tags: bayesian, validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Validation techniques for hierarchical model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26970/validation-techniques-for-hierarchical-model)

I already posted [this to Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135641/validation-techniques-for-hierarchical-model), but I realized this would probably be a better place to post to.

I have a hierarchical model that I need to validate. My model is as follows: we have a collection of $λ_i$ that we draw from ${\rm Gamma}(α,β)$. Then, we draw our data point yi from ${\rm Poisson}(λ_i)$. I get a joint distribution of $α,β,λ_i$ via a Gibbs sampler combined with a Metropolis step. This part is fine, no problems with implementation. My question is how do I validate such a model? I have my set of data, each one corresponding to one particular $λ_i$. I'm not sure what statistical tests/ other steps I should take to check are.
Thanks!